# jQuery: getting variable value when PHP page opens itself with Ajax .post call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file, let's call it mypage.php. I go to mypage.php?page=1. Now `$_GET['page']` gives me 1 without problems.

The page mypage.php also calls mypage.php with jQuery.

```
setInterval(function() {
  var c = 10;
  var p = 1;

  jQuery.post("mypage.php", {
    check: c,
    page: p
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert('OK');
  });
}, 6000);
```

How can I get the value of `page` when the post method has been used? `$_POST['page']` does not help.

Comment: Is your ajax request working in general? Any errors in your console?

Comment: What do you mean "does not help"? Are you stating that $_POST array is empty or unset? Is mypage.php receiving a page hit at all?

Comment: `$_POST['page']` is empty. I can see the alert every 6 seconds, so I think that the code works fine. All I need is to get the value of `page`.

Answer (score 1):

At first look $_POST['page'] seem to be impossible to be empty ! (if not others issues)

put this in your mypage.php

```
if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    echo $_POST['page'];
}
```

and change

```
alert('OK');
```

to

```
alert(data,status);
```

And / or add fail() to manage errors:

```
  .fail(function(Xhr,status) {
   console.log( Xhr,status);
  })
```